# Animated GIF in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have created label with animated gif using following code in application class extending JFrame

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("Icons/AnimatedSpinnerSmall.gif");
JLabel lblAnimatedSpinnerSmall = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url));
```

Thereafter during run time one of the class methods calls another class method which in turn calls another class method and so on. Ultimately a class methods include following code to display animated gif in application's main frame window

```
  getContentPane().add(lblAnimatedSpinnerSmall);
  lblAnimatedSpinnerSmall.setBounds(44 + currentChannelNumber * 110, 140, 32, 32);
   getContentPane().repaint();
```

For some unknown reason, the animation does not start immediately but starts only after when a code to display some message is flashed like following

```
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello Now Animation Starts");
```

Please guide me - how anmation can be made to start immediately.

Surprisingly in this same application, animated gif added during execution of application class's constructor works fine and as expected.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Start a new project, add the label and animated gif to a `JFrame` and see if that works, if that works then it's something else in your code (likely blocking the EDT)

Comment: If it's working when placed in the constructor, odds are `getContentPane().repaint()` isn't working for your needs. I suggest repainting the actual `JLabel`.

Comment: To clear misunderstanding I am reproducing complete code of my application in which animated gif starts at different points of time when located at different places within application